# How to use two way data binding in Blazor Component Library Project

Tags: blazor

I would like to share some basic input components between Blazor projects but I seem to be missing something in my shared razor project when it comes to supporting the data binding.

Using the Microsoft component binding example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/components).

The Component Code looks like this:

```
    Password: <input
    value="@Password"
    @oninput="OnPasswordChanged"
    type="@(showPassword ? "text" : "password")" />

<label><input type="checkbox" @bind="showPassword" />Show password</label>

@code {
    private bool showPassword;

    [Parameter]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> PasswordChanged { get; set; }

    private Task OnPasswordChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Password = e.Value.ToString();
        return PasswordChanged.InvokeAsync(Password);
    }
}
```

and then this is used like this:

```
<PasswordBox @bind-Password="password" />

@code {
    string password;
}
```

When the component is declared directly in my Blazor WebAssembly project this works as expected. However, if I move the component to a library so that I use it in shared components I get a compile error:

> Error     The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute
>   'bind-Password'. Bind attributes should be of the form 'bind' or
>   'bind-value' along with their corresponding optional parameters like
>   'bind-value:event', 'bind:format'

My guess is that I'm missing a reference in my shared project which handles these bind attributes - but I don't know how to find how what I need to reference.

I currently reference:

- NETStandard.Library 2.1
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components (3.1.5)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web (3.1.5)
- System.Net.Http.Json (3.2.1)

This seems enough for normal attribute binding for fields and passing values from one component to another - but not for this specific two-way bind syntax. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are your components defined in a Razor Component Library ?
2. Did you add a reference to your Blazor App for the library project?
3. Most importantly, Do you define routable ( decorated with the @page directive) components in your library projects ?
4. Do you have a SharedObjects project where you define objects that are used in the Razor Component Library project and the Blazor App project? Do you add a reference to the SharedObjects project to both projects ?

Comment: Missing namespace _Imports.razor (d'oh)